# Olympus E-M10 Mark II - Auto Focus Point Lock

Tags: olympus-omd

When I use the Super Control Menu to set the AF target ( and using Single Target mode), while I know to do this, it subsequently moves while I'm taking photos. I'm not sure what makes it move - other than doing it purposefully - but it moves.

Does anyone know how to lock it in position (I prefer the centre cell)?

I've researched this in the Instruction Manual and on the net but cannot find a way of locking it.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer...thanks all.  The answer lies in setting the Home position of the AF grid to the middle position (or whatever position you want as Home), then assigning the Home position to a Fn button. So, by pressing the Fn button I reset the AF target point.

Comment: A work around, not the solution. Thanks for the tip, because the wandering focus point is one of my biggest complaints!